# Connecting multiple columns of a table

Tags: python, mysql

- I am writing code for taking data from multiple columns of a `MySQL`
  database.
- In my coding I need to print the lines that are present in my
  database, I did it and it works fine but it's not printing the next
  column word match.
- I have a text file `"qwer.txt"` which contains`LINE1:"I have a car".LINE2:"I have a phone"`
- My `tablename` is `'adarsh1'` in which the `"A1"` column consists of car
  and `"A2"` consists of phone.

According to my coding it prints `"I have a car"` instead of `"I have a car"` *and* `"I have a phone"`.

So, what is the problem in my coding preventing me from printing both the line since it presents in both the column of a table?

---

```
import MySQLdb


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT A1,A2 FROM adarsh1")


# commit your changes
db.commit()

keywords=[]
#here fetchall() gets all the rows and we append carnames to key words

for i in cursor.fetchall():
    keywords.append(i[1])

with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
                print line
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think your question is a little hard to understand. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: This should work. I guess there is another problem with what you want to actually achieve. You should rephrase your question.

Comment: I mean line1 contains:'I have a car' and line2:'I have a phone'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only append one column to the keyword. You probably should append both i[0] and i[1]:

```
    import MySQLdb


    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL select statement
    cursor.execute("SELECT A1,A2 FROM adarsh1")


    # commit your changes
    db.commit()

    keywords=[]
    #here fetchall() gets all the rows and we append carnames to key words

    for i in cursor.fetchall():
        keywords.append(i[0])
        keywords.append(i[1])

    with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for key in keywords:
                if key in line:
                    print line
```